# Filter objects in array with field values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, filter

I want my method PrintDrillsNeedingBitReplacement to only show me the drills with the boolean value true to this question. My current method prints every drill, wether or not it needs bit replacement. The array is being created from a .txt file with a couple of other objects in it so I struggle to filter it out depending on index value. Further down you can see my attempt. Would really appriciate detailed explanation if possible.

```
public class Program {
    private static final String  DRILL = "Drill";
    private static final String  SAW = "Saw";
    List<Equipment> equipmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Equipment> readFromFile() throws IOException {
        File equipment = new File("equipment.txt");
        equipmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        fields = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        String type = null;
        Equipment equip = null;
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(equipment)) {
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = reader.nextLine();
                if (isTypeLine(line)) {
                    if (type != null) {
                        switch (type) {
                            case DRILL:
                                equip = createDrill(fields);
                                break;
                            case SAW:
                                equip = createSaw(fields);
                                break;
                            default:
                                equip = null;
                        }
                        if (equip != null) {
                            equipmentList.add(equip);
                        }
                    }
                    fields.clear();
                    type = line;
                }
                else {
                    fields.add(line);
                }
            }
            if (type != null) {
                switch (type) {
                    case DRILL:
                        equip = createDrill(fields);
                        break;
                    case SAW:
                        equip = createSaw(fields);
                        break;
                    default:
                        equip = null;
                }
                if (equip != null) {
                    equipmentList.add(equip);
                }
            }
            return equipmentList;
        }
    }

    public List<Equipment> printDrillsNeedingBitReplacement() {
        for (Equipment equipment : equipmentList) {
            if (equipment.getEquipmentName() == DRILL) {
                createDrill(fields).getNeedsNewBit().equals(true);
                System.out.println(equipment);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Drill createDrill(List<String> fields) {
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(fields.get(0));
        String locker = fields.get(1);
        Integer year = Integer.valueOf(fields.get(2));
        Boolean batteryPowered = Boolean.valueOf(fields.get(3));
        Boolean needsNewBit = Boolean.valueOf(fields.get(4));
        Drill drill = new Drill(DRILL, id, locker, year, batteryPowered, needsNewBit);
        return drill;
    }

    private boolean isTypeLine(String line) {
        return DRILL.equals(line)  ||  SAW.equals(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (equipment.getEquipmentName() == DRILL)` are those strings?

Comment: Also, what do you expect this `createDrill(fields).getNeedsNewBit().equals(true);` to do on its own?

Comment: I have just tried to write many different lines of code to see what happens. I am a student, so I lack knowledge of how all the syntax works

Answer (score 0):

Try java streams:

```
equipmentList().stream().filter(e -> e.getDrill == true).collect(Collectors.toList())
```